# How to implement drag-and-drop on a Collection View in Xamarin.Forms for iPhone

Tags: xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop, collectionview

I have a Collection View, to implement the drag-and-drop on iPhone I have created a Custom Renderer to use a functionality present on Xamarin.iOS but it doesn't work.

```
public class CollectionViewDragRenderer : CollectionViewRenderer
{
    private bool _gestureIsSet;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ItemsView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            if (!_gestureIsSet)
            {
                if (Control.PreferredFocusEnvironments[0] is UICollectionView collectionView)
                {
                    var gestureRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(gesture =>
                    {
                        switch (gesture.State)
                        {
                            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
                                var selectedIndexPath = collectionView.IndexPathForItemAtPoint(
                                        gesture.LocationInView(collectionView));
                                if (selectedIndexPath != null)
                                {
                                    collectionView.BeginInteractiveMovementForItem(selectedIndexPath);
                                }
                                break;
                            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
                                collectionView.UpdateInteractiveMovement(gesture.LocationInView(collectionView));
                                LogBroker.Instance.TraceDebug("position " + gesture.LocationInView(collectionView));
                                break;
                            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
                                collectionView.EndInteractiveMovement();
                                break;
                            default:
                                collectionView.CancelInteractiveMovement();
                                break;
                        }
                    });

                    collectionView.AddGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer);
                }

                _gestureIsSet = true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs changedProperty)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, changedProperty);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            if (!_gestureIsSet)
            {
                if (Control.PreferredFocusEnvironments[0] is UICollectionView collectionView)
                {
                    var gestureRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(gesture =>
                    {
                        switch (gesture.State)
                        {
                            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
                                var selectedIndexPath = collectionView.IndexPathForItemAtPoint(
                                        gesture.LocationInView(collectionView));
                                if (selectedIndexPath != null)
                                {
                                    collectionView.BeginInteractiveMovementForItem(selectedIndexPath);
                                }
                                break;
                            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
                                //CGPoint targetPoint = new CGPoint(Control.Center.X, Control.Center.Y + 150);
                                collectionView.UpdateInteractiveMovement(gesture.LocationInView(collectionView));
                                LogBroker.Instance.TraceDebug("position " + gesture.LocationInView(collectionView));
                                break;
                            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
                                collectionView.EndInteractiveMovement();
                                break;
                            default:
                                collectionView.CancelInteractiveMovement();
                                break;
                        }
                    });

                    collectionView.AddGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer);
                }

                _gestureIsSet = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a known issue in the CollectionViewRenderer so the line shown below has been added to extract the UICollectionView from the Control :

```
if (Control.PreferredFocusEnvironments[0] is UICollectionView collectionView)
```

I've tried to switch `: CollectionViewRenderer` with 
`ViewRenderer<CollectionView, UICollectionView` but the items of the Collection View have not been shown anymore on the screen.

The logs of the position given by `gesture.LocationInView(collectionView)` are correct and change accordingly with the movement of the finger on the screen but the tapped item does not move.

Comment: Check https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/ios11/DragAndDropCollectionView

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Sharpnado `HorizontalListView`. Therefore you won't need any renderers. Then when the drag and drop feature will be implemented in the future `CollectionView`, you can just swap it.

It has a `Grid` layout mode (which can be a list view if you set `ColumnCount=1`):

https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms/wiki/HorizontalListView-Grid-And-Carousel#grid-layout

Grid with 3 columns:

```xml
<renderedViews:HorizontalListView CollectionPadding="16"
                                  ItemSpacing="8"
                                  EnableDragAndDrop="True"
                                  ColumnCount="3"
                                  ItemHeight="120"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding SillyPeople}"
                                  ListLayout="Grid">
```

or a list view:

```xml
<renderedViews:HorizontalListView CollectionPadding="8"
                                  ItemSpacing="8"
                                  EnableDragAndDrop="True"
                                  ColumnCount="1"
                                  ItemHeight="120"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding SillyPeople}"
                                  ListLayout="Grid">
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that this is a valid answer but we have a huge project and the Sharpnado has given some problems on the Android side.

Comment: too bad you didn't report the issues, they are fixed very quickly :)